# How do I get the location from an unidentified coordinate system point?

Tags: coordinate-system, well-known-text, epsg

I'm working in C# and I have this JSON:

```
{"id":429,"name":null,"address":"10 Wooleys La.",
"city":"Great Neck", "decadeBlt":0,"totalUnits":12,"propertyType":null,
"yea‌​rBlt":0,"expectedCom‌​pletion":0,"downtown‌​Area":null,"aptConve‌​rsion":0,
"detailedIn‌​fo":null,
"wkt":"POIN‌​T (-8207941 4982429)"}
```

I need to get the WGS84 latitude and longitude of this point (it's in Long Island, NY).

Comment: It might help if you tell where on the earth this place is.

Comment: Could be DDMMSS.S or DDMM.MMM if they are lat/long... But could be another kind of reference system. Knowing the app. place would help a lot

Comment: Let me see if I understood your question - you have a coordinate pair in an unknown projection, for which you want the lat/lon values?

Comment: The coordinates are in EPSG::3857, AKA "Web Mercator".

Answer (score 1):

By checking the reported coordinates and location using ArcGIS (ArcMap specifically), I was able to identify these coordinates:

POIN‌​T (-8207941 4982429)

as being in EPSG::3857. Colloquially called Web Mercator, its EPSG name is "WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator". The [EPSG geodetic parameter registry](http://www.epsg-registry.org) is a large repository of coordinate reference systems and transformations.

It uses a spherical Mercator algorithm with a radius of 6378137.0 m. If you unproject the coordinates to latitude-longitude, they'll automatically be on WGS 84 (EPSG::4326).

The coordinates are in easting (X), northing (Y) order.

Disclosure: I'm a member of the subcommittee that maintains the EPSG registry.